# how do i replace \ character?

Tags: javascript, replace, while-loop

i got the following code

```
replaceforever: function(string,find,replace){
while(_.contains(string,find)){
  string.replace(find,replace);
}
return string;}
```

and i am sending to it something like `'./routes\admin\articles.js','\\','/'`
but it always seem to enter the while loop once and change it all with one '/' as result :|
instead of being a nice `./routes/admin/articles.js`

can anyone explain to me please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use a regex? Also note that if you're trying this with './routes\admin\articles.js' as a string literal, you'll need to escape those backslashes.

Comment: What's `_` in the `replaceforever` function?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your testing, not with the code (assuming you are using underscore.js; 
using regular expressions would be more sensible).

You need to escape your backslashes in the input string:

```
replaceforever('./routes\\admin\\articles.js','\\','/');
```

`'./routes\admin\articles.js'`, on the other hand, evaluates to `'./routesadminarticles.js'`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, this will do a global replacement:

```
stringVariable.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Comment: The result is: "./routesadminarticles.js"

Comment: yeah, sorry. He needs to double backslashes \\

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is actually that your while-loop isn't being entered *at all*, rather than that it's being entered once. Note that your input actually already has a `/`, and I think that's what you're seeing.

This line:

```
string.replace(find,replace);
```

creates a new string with the specified replacement . . . and then throws it away. So if your while-loop were being entered even once, it would actually be an infinite loop, because the loop body doesn't actually do anything. Instead, you need to store the result in the variable `string`:

```
string = string.replace(find,replace);
```

But I'm not sure this method is really a good idea anyway. JavaScript already offers "replace-all" functionality, using regexes:

```
result = input.replace(/\\/g, '/');
```

Comment: The result is "./routesadminarticles.js"

Comment: @tntu: No, it's not. What makes you think so?

Comment: @tntu - See my comment on the question. If you're calling that function directly with a string literal, the backslashes are escaping the characters following them. You need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score -2):

First: `string.replace()` will replace ALL the matches, so there is no need of iteration :)

Second: `string.replace()` will return a NEW string, it wont change the object used.

So you need something like:

```
replaceforever: function (string,find,replace) {  
    return string.replace(find,replace);  
}
```

Comment: It will not replace all the matches when invoked with a string as the first argument. It will replace the first match. To replace all matches you need to invoke it with a regular expression, with the `g` flag.